# DNS への通信は暗号化できる?

Tags: network, dns

例えば ngrok では、ローカルのポートをグローバルなサーバーに forward できますが、その際に割り当てられるホスト名は、ランダムなIDが割り当てられるため、悪意の第三者はそのフォワード先のホストへアクセスできず、そこまで危険ではない、という理解をしています。

例: 903535c62e7e.ngrok.io

しかし、この際に、例えばこのドメインにアクセスしようとすると、このドメインに対して DNS クエリが走り、そのクエリは特に暗号化などはされていないので、中間の攻撃者は、その値を確認しようと思えば確認できると思っています。

## 質問

DNS のクエリを暗号化することは可能でしょうか?

Comment: DNS-over-HTTPS では事足りませんか？ https://developers-jp.googleblog.com/2020/06/secure-dns.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DNS over HTTPS(DoH),DNS over TLSがあります(DoT)。クライアント側に対応が必要ですが。

もっとも、ngrokは「秘密のトンネル」ではないので、クエリを暗号化したところで何かが安全になるわけではありません。